# onclicks that play a song and change image at bottom of screen

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have created a simple music player that displays three songs. Upon clicking on an individual song, I am looking to change an image at the bottom of the screen. Here is my html and js. Any help would be appreciated. I am rather new to this. Would it be best to do two functions such as onclick changeSong(); changePic()?

```
<div id="container">
    <audio id="player">
        <source src="assets/Beethoven-Symphony5-1.mp3">
    </audio>
    <button id = "btnPlay">Play</button>
    <button id = "btnPause">Pause</button>
    <button id = "btnStop">Stop</button>
    <label for="rngVolume">Volume</label>
    <input type="range" id="rngVolume" min="0" max="1" step=".01" value=".5" data-highlight="true" onchange="changeVolume()" />
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role = "list-divider">Songs</li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="changeSong('Beethoven-Symphony5-1')">01 Symphony 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="changeSong('Beethoven-violin-sonata1-1')">02 Sonata 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="changeSong('bizet-jeux-d-enfants-poupee')">03 Bizet</a>     
    </ul>
    <img src="img/Beethoven2.jpg">
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <output id="timeOut">Elasped Time:</output>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the image source and where is your image tag? It could be as simple as dynamically updating the source of an image tag when the song changes but you need to have something already in place we can work with. Check out other solutions which load images dynamically and see what works for you. When you like an implementation add it to your code and we can work from that.

Comment: No need to make a new function for one line of code. Just set the image's new `src` value in your existing function. Also, the `a` elements are unnecessary and semantically incorrect. Just make the `li` elements be the elements that have the `click` event handlers and remove the `a` elements completely.

Comment: Just added the img tag. Yeah I believe I see what Scott was referring to. I had only used a elements from previous books that I was taught from last year. So I will change that habit. When I added to existing function, I kept getting .src not defined.

Comment: Unfortunately, because of the way HTML, CSS and JavaScript have evolved over the years, many (and I do mean many) old, antiquated and incorrect techniques for web development still persist today. Worse, many of these are still being taught simply because a small fraction of web developers truly understand the purpose of the languages of the web and how to properly integrate them. Students in universities (who are paying for this education) are often being taught incorrect standards. Good luck and feel better. ;)

Comment: Appreciate the wishes Scott. Yeah that is the truth. I will continue to try and figure this out. Appreciate the advice.

Comment: Thanks all. Stepped away for a few and figured it out.